# Strugling with Samsung NP300V5AH and bumblebee on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, samsung, bumblebee

I have some problems with optimus on 12.10. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu and then followed the official wiki - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee.
Installation process went fine. But after restart i can't use "optirun SOMEAPP". The display goes to command line, I can't see any of desktop elements just lots of text. One time it went back and said the default phrase of "can't connect to driver" or something like that. optirun -status gives me:

```
[ 1231.231171] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path tatus was incorrect.
[ 1231.231297] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

but sudo bubmblebeed says:

```
[ 1365.303793] [ERROR]Daemon already running, pid 1031
```

My uname -a gives

```
Linux plastic-lap 3.5.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 13 17:49:53 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

lspci -nn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 520MX] [10de:1051] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 130 [8086:0896] (rev 34)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
```

I couldn't figure this problem out. Can anybody help me? And bay the way it looks funny when official step-by-step instructions does not work.. :)
Help me I'm really in need of my nvidia GPU especially when I'm invited to Steam beta (at last). :D

Update by request:
Hare is the output of grep bumblebee /var/log/syslog | pastebinit

```
Dec 12 17:13:49 plastic-lap bumblebeed[1029]: X did not start properly
Dec 12 21:31:59 plastic-lap bumblebeed[1023]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
Dec 12 21:44:14 plastic-lap bumblebeed[1023]: Received Terminated signal.
Dec 12 21:44:14 plastic-lap bumblebeed[2777]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
Dec 12 21:50:39 plastic-lap bumblebeed[1011]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
Dec 12 21:52:07 plastic-lap bumblebeed[986]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
Dec 12 21:54:27 plastic-lap bumblebeed[986]: Received Terminated signal.
Dec 12 21:54:27 plastic-lap bumblebeed[2461]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
Dec 12 21:58:43 plastic-lap bumblebeed[2461]: Received Terminated signal.
Dec 12 22:06:40 plastic-lap bumblebeed[4357]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
Dec 12 22:07:17 plastic-lap bumblebeed[4357]: Received Terminated signal.
Dec 12 22:07:18 plastic-lap bumblebeed[4357]: The PCI config space could not be written fully at offset 0x1; 0 bytes have been written; error: Interrupted system call
Dec 12 22:07:18 plastic-lap bumblebeed[5876]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
Dec 12 22:08:44 plastic-lap bumblebeed[1031]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
Dec 12 22:51:05 plastic-lap bumblebeed[923]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
Dec 12 22:51:46 plastic-lap bumblebeed[923]: X did not start properly
Dec 12 22:53:17 plastic-lap bumblebeed[1043]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
```

Anything else needed?

Ok one of the problems may be related to this:

cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch

```
0000:01:00.0 OFF
```

Strange is that that I have Linux headers and bbswitch installed..

I did what Salem suggested, but still no luck.. This is what optirun prints:
optirun -vv glxspheres

```
[   34.815833] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[   34.816114] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[   34.954179] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.0.1 starting...
[   34.954208] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[   34.954212] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[   34.954216] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[   34.954220] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
[   34.954224] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[   34.954227] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[   36.807365] [INFO]Response: No - error: X did not start properly

[   36.807387] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: X did not start properly

[   36.807393] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[   36.807415] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[   36.807420] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

This is my /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=true
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia
Module=nvidia
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

And this is my /etc/bublebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    Option "AutoAddDevices" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device1"
    Driver "nvidia"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"
EndSection
```

It just don't want to make me happy. ;)

UPDATE:
This is output of sudo /usr/sbin/bumblebeed -vv --debug:

```
[ 1031.139866] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 1031.140691] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[ 1031.140757] [DEBUG]Skipping auto-detection, using configured driver 'nvidia'
[ 1031.141025] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modinfo started, PID 3751.
[ 1031.141129] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modinfo
[ 1031.142301] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[ 1031.142717] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modinfo started, PID 3752.
[ 1031.142809] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modinfo
[ 1031.143868] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[ 1031.144172] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modinfo started, PID 3753.
[ 1031.144291] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modinfo
[ 1031.146782] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[ 1031.147078] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modinfo started, PID 3754.
[ 1031.147180] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modinfo
[ 1031.149896] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[ 1031.149982] [DEBUG]bbswitch has been detected.
[ 1031.149997] [INFO]Switching method 'bbswitch' is available and will be used.
[ 1031.150011] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 1031.150023] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 1031.150035] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 1031.150047] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
[ 1031.150061] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 1031.150073] [DEBUG] pidfile: /var/run/bumblebeed.pid
[ 1031.150085] [DEBUG] xorg.conf file: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
[ 1031.150098] [DEBUG] ModulePath: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
[ 1031.150110] [DEBUG] GID name: bumblebee
[ 1031.150122] [DEBUG] Power method: auto
[ 1031.150134] [DEBUG] Stop X on exit: 1
[ 1031.150146] [DEBUG] Driver: nvidia
[ 1031.150158] [DEBUG] Driver module: nvidia-current
[ 1031.150170] [DEBUG] Card shutdown state: 0
[ 1031.150401] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modinfo started, PID 3755.
[ 1031.150509] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modinfo
[ 1031.153524] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[ 1031.153581] [DEBUG]Configuration test passed.
[ 1031.154625] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.0.1 started
[ 1031.154835] [INFO]Initialization completed - now handling client requests
```

Then in other term I ran optirun glxspheres and got

```
optirun glxspheres
[ 1520.703053] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: X did not start properly
[ 1520.703098] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

The first term outputs:

```
[ 1518.419583] [DEBUG]Accepted new connection
[ 1518.620300] [INFO]Switching dedicated card ON [bbswitch]
[ 1519.045660] [DEBUG]there is no PCI configuration space to restore
[ 1519.046048] [INFO]Loading driver nvidia (module nvidia-current)
[ 1519.046323] [DEBUG]Process modprobe started, PID 4933.
[ 1519.214041] [DEBUG]Process with PID 4933 returned code 0
[ 1519.214317] [INFO]Starting X server on display :8.
[ 1519.214594] [DEBUG]Process Xorg started, PID 4934.
[ 1520.600968] [DEBUG][XORG] X.Org X Server 1.13.0
[ 1520.601046] [DEBUG]Process with PID 4934 terminated with 9
[ 1520.601015] [DEBUG][XORG] Release Date: 2012-09-05
[ 1520.601085] [DEBUG][XORG] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 1520.601099] [DEBUG][XORG] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-26-generic i686 Ubuntu
[ 1520.601113] [DEBUG][XORG] Current Operating System: Linux plastic-lap 3.5.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 13 17:49:53 UTC 2012 i686
[ 1520.601127] [DEBUG][XORG] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=95400e10-8964-4152-bdaf-65f714178228 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[ 1520.601141] [DEBUG][XORG] Build Date: 27 November 2012  07:44:37AM
[ 1520.601157] [DEBUG][XORG] xorg-server 2:1.13.0-0ubuntu6.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[ 1520.601172] [DEBUG][XORG] Current version of pixman: 0.26.0
[ 1520.601184] [DEBUG][XORG]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
[ 1520.601200] [DEBUG][XORG]    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 1520.601215] [DEBUG][XORG] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
[ 1520.601228] [DEBUG][XORG]    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
[ 1520.601248] [DEBUG][XORG]    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 1520.601263] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.8.log", Time: Sun Dec 16 20:13:01 2012
[ 1520.601278] [DEBUG][XORG] (++) Using config file: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia"
[ 1520.601292] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 1520.601306] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[ 1520.601319] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 1520.601333] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 1520.601349] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 1520.601362] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
[ 1520.601375] [DEBUG][XORG]    Using the first device section listed.
[ 1520.601389] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) |   |-->Device "Device1"
[ 1520.601401] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
[ 1520.601416] [DEBUG][XORG]    Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 1520.601431] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "true"
[ 1520.601443] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) Automatically adding devices
[ 1520.601456] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 1520.601469] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 1520.601484] [DEBUG][XORG] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 1520.601497] [DEBUG][XORG]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 1520.601513] [DEBUG][XORG] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[ 1520.601526] [DEBUG][XORG]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 1520.601541] [DEBUG][XORG] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[ 1520.601555] [DEBUG][XORG]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 1520.601571] [DEBUG][XORG] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[ 1520.601585] [DEBUG][XORG]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 1520.601606] [DEBUG][XORG] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[ 1520.601619] [DEBUG][XORG]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 1520.601639] [DEBUG][XORG] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[ 1520.601654] [DEBUG][XORG]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 1520.601668] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) FontPath set to:
[ 1520.601681] [DEBUG][XORG]    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
[ 1520.601695] [DEBUG][XORG]    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
[ 1520.601709] [DEBUG][XORG]    built-ins
[ 1520.601723] [DEBUG][XORG] (++) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 1520.601738] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
[ 1520.601752] [DEBUG][XORG]    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 1520.601767] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Loader magic: 0xb77c4640
[ 1520.601780] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 1520.601792] [DEBUG][XORG]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 1520.601806] [DEBUG][XORG]    X.Org Video Driver: 13.0
[ 1520.601821] [DEBUG][XORG]    X.Org XInput driver : 18.0
[ 1520.601835] [DEBUG][XORG]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[ 1520.601849] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 1520.601863] [DEBUG][XORG] setversion 1.4 failed
[ 1520.601877] [DEBUG][XORG] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1051:144d:c0b6 rev 161, Mem @ 0xe0000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, 0xc0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00003000/128
[ 1520.601892] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[ 1520.601904] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[ 1520.601917] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[ 1520.601930] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[ 1520.601942] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[ 1520.601961] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[ 1520.601974] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[ 1520.601986] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[ 1520.602001] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[ 1520.602014] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[ 1520.602026] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[ 1520.602039] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[ 1520.602051] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[ 1520.602064] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[ 1520.602076] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[ 1520.602089] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[ 1520.602101] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[ 1520.602114] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[ 1520.602126] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[ 1520.602139] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[ 1520.602154] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[ 1520.602167] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[ 1520.602180] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[ 1520.602192] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[ 1520.602205] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[ 1520.602218] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[ 1520.602231] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[ 1520.602243] [DEBUG][XORG] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[ 1520.602256] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 1520.602268] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/libglx.so
[ 1520.602281] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[ 1520.602337] [DEBUG][XORG]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[ 1520.602353] [DEBUG][XORG]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[ 1520.602368] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.64  Tue Oct 30 11:31:18 PDT 2012
[ 1520.602381] [DEBUG][XORG] Loading extension GLX
[ 1520.602398] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[ 1520.602410] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[ 1520.602423] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[ 1520.602436] [DEBUG][XORG]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[ 1520.602450] [DEBUG][XORG]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 1520.602464] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.64  Tue Oct 30 11:11:05 PDT 2012
[ 1520.602479] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[ 1520.602494] [DEBUG][XORG] (--) using VT number 7
[ 1520.602507] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 1520.602520] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 1520.602532] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[ 1520.602544] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 1520.602557] [DEBUG][XORG]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 1.0.0
[ 1520.602572] [DEBUG][XORG]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 1520.602586] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[ 1520.602598] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[ 1520.602611] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[ 1520.602623] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 1520.602636] [DEBUG][XORG]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 1.0.0
[ 1520.602650] [DEBUG][XORG]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 1520.602667] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[ 1520.602679] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[ 1520.602692] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[ 1520.602704] [DEBUG][XORG] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
[ 1520.602717] [DEBUG][XORG]    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[ 1520.602732] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 1520.602744] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[ 1520.602757] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 1520.602769] [DEBUG][XORG] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[ 1520.602782] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" "true"
[ 1520.602794] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "UseEDID" "false"
[ 1520.602810] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
[ 1520.602823] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[ 1520.602836] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) NVIDIA(0): Ignoring EDIDs
[ 1520.602848] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "UseDisplayDevice" set to "none"; enabling NoScanout
[ 1520.602861] [DEBUG][XORG] (**) NVIDIA(0):     mode
[ 1520.702963] [ERROR]X did not start properly
[ 1520.803163] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
```

By the way when i run optirun SOMETHING my screen goes to comand line with full screen of text then i should press ctrl+alt+f7 to go back to my desktop.

Comment: Please update your answer with the output of `grep bumblebee /var/log/syslog | pastebinit`.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Don't you get any error/warning when running `bumblebeed -vv` manually? Try to run it adding `--debug`.

Comment: Question updated with bumblebeed --debug --vv output.

Comment: The only difference i see is in `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf/nvidia`: i have `Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"`. You can try to change that.

Comment: It doesn't mater is it false or true, bumblebee (or xorg) still refuses to start X properly.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` is ok, your graphic should only be on when you run a program using `optirun`.

Make sure you have your configuration right in `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` with those values:

- KeepUnusedXServer=false
- TurnCardOffAtExit=true
- Driver=nvidia

Every time you change this file, restart bumblebee using `sudo restart bumblebeed`. If it still doesn't work try replacing *nvidia* with *nouveau*.

Also make sure you have installed `bumblebee-nvidia` package and that you are not using an experimental nvidia driver (nvidia-experimental-310, for example).

If it still doesn't work, the best way to diagnose the problem is starting it in verbose mode

```
sudo stop bumblebeed
sudo /usr/sbin/bumblebeed -vv
```

Then you can start `optirun SOME_PROGRAM` in another terminal and post the errors you get on `bumblebeed` terminal.

Tip: after you get this to work, as you want to use it for gaming you should take a look at [primus](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/primus-better-performance-and-less.html).